# Can hard drives have their own sleep settings?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive, power-management

Is there a tool that will allow me to set the sleep settings on a per-drive basis? I've recently done the [optibay mod](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pIwMs7ZgFws) on my MBP so I have an HD+SSD setup and I'd like to be able to make the magnetic drive sleep as much as is possible (I boot off the SSD) to save battery. The machine's power consumption has ramped up since I did the mod.

Comment: Did you not try System Preferences > Energy Saver > Put Hard disks to sleep when possible ?

Comment: As I hoped the title of my question might imply, I need to have different settings for different drives. The one in System Preferences seems to apply to *all* drives and I don't want the SSD to sleep ever.

Comment: If you give a reason for why you don’t want your SSD to sleep (I *think* it doesn’t sleep, even with the preference turned on), perhaps I can help you better.

Comment: Because I've heard numerous reports of Apple machines not waking from sleep when booting from SSD. e.g.  http://blog.alutam.com/2012/04/01/optimizing-macos-x-lion-for-ssd/#no_hdd_sleep